# Linq new statement selection conditionally

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i need to select data to populate a DataGrid in MVC Asp.net with entity framework. When i select all values i need to have values from three tables connected: e, category and product. The connection is always 1 to 0 or 1. I have selected all walue with this code but when there isn't a category.name associated i naturally have an exception. What is the best way to do this?Do i need use if statment in New constructor?Or other?

```
var products = from e in dbResult
                           select new
                           {
                               e.Id,
                               e.Title,
                               e.Price,
                               e.Quantity,
                               e.category.nome,
                               e.Product.Sottotitolo,
                               e.Procuct.Provenienza
                           };
```

Thanks to all

Comment: What exception did you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to C# 6 one way would be:

```
var products = from e in dbResult
                           select new
                           {
                               e.Id,
                               e.Title,
                               e.Price,
                               e.Quantity,
                               Noma = e.category == null ? "" : e.category.nome,
                               Sottotitolo = e.Product == null ? "" : e.Product.Sottotitolo,
                               Provenienza = e.Procuct == null ? "" : e.Procuct.Provenienza
                           };
```

With C# 6 you can use the  [`?.` null-conditional member access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) operator:

```
var products = from e in dbResult
                           select new
                           {
                               e.Id,
                               e.Title,
                               e.Price,
                               e.Quantity,
                               Noma = e.category?.nome,
                               Sottotitolo = e.Product?.Sottotitolo,
                               Provenienza = e.Procuct?.Provenienza
                           };
```

Note that the field values in the latter method will be `null` instead of empty strings.